# Send multiple directories to the Recycle Bin with FileSystem.DeleteDirectory

Tags: c#, file-io

Making a file browser with loads of functions, coming back to fine tune some of my methods to find this:

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.SelectedItems)
{
    FileSystem.DeleteDirectory(item.SubItems[3].Text,  
        UIOption.AllDialogs,
        RecycleOption.SendToRecycleBin,
        UICancelOption.ThrowException);
}
```

which works great to send a SINGLE directory or file to the recycle bin, but it will prompt for every selected item. Not great for deleting a pile of files and folders.

Any way to achieve this without the excess prompts? Or do I have to delve into SHFILEOPSTRUCT?

Thanks for your help, so far 90% of my questions were already answered here, best website ever.

Comment: According to [this](http://www.daveamenta.com/2008-05/c-delete-a-file-to-the-recycle-bin/) (and other numerous articles) you have only that option SHFILEOPSTRUCT

Comment: Should have added this as an answer Steve, the "answer" below is getting all the votes. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, I will try to build  an example with SHFILEOPSTRUCT and then will put an answer. Wait

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be the only way to do what you have required
Moving the files and directory **to the recycle bin without prompt**

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Win32ApiUtils
{
    // Don't declare a value for the Pack size. If you omit it, the correct value is used when  
    // marshaling and a single SHFILEOPSTRUCT can be used for both 32-bit and 64-bit operation.
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public struct SHFILEOPSTRUCT
    {
        public IntPtr hwnd;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public int wFunc;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string pFrom;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string pTo;            
        public ushort fFlags;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public bool fAnyOperationsAborted;
        public IntPtr hNameMappings;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string lpszProgressTitle;
   }

   [DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
   static extern int SHFileOperation(ref SHFILEOPSTRUCT FileOp);
   const int FO_DELETE = 3;
   const int FOF_ALLOWUNDO = 0x40;
   const int FOF_NOCONFIRMATION = 0x10; //Don't prompt the user.; 

   public static int DeleteFilesToRecycleBin(string filename)
   {
        SHFILEOPSTRUCT shf = new SHFILEOPSTRUCT();
        shf.wFunc = FO_DELETE;
        shf.fFlags = FOF_ALLOWUNDO | FOF_NOCONFIRMATION;
        shf.pFrom = filename + "\0";  // <--- this "\0" is critical !!!!!
        int result = SHFileOperation(ref shf);
        // Any value different from zero is an error to lookup 
        return result;

   }
```

}

```
   foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.SelectedItems)
   {
        int result = Win32ApiUtils.DeleteFilesToRecycleBin(item.SubItems[3].Text);
        if(result != 0) ...... // ??? throw ??? message to user and contine ???
   }
```

**-- Warning --**
This code needs to be tested. I have found the layout of SHFILEOPSTRUCT on [PInvoke site](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/SHFILEOPSTRUCT.html) and on that link there are some notes about the declaration of the strings used.

Well. tested on my Win7 64bit with a single directory to delete. Works like a charm....

Comment: Will test when I get home, I also use x64 but I've come across a couple of tips to make it compatible with both. At any rate it's answered my question, thanks.

Comment: May also be worth noting this requires 
Using System.Runtime.InteropServices

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want the prompts, you could use [Directory.Delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f.aspx) instead of the `FileSystem` method.  This will delete the directory and files and subdirectories (provided you specify that you want it to do so).

Comment: Yes, but this will outright delete the files, not send them to the recycle bin and so doesn't suit my purpose.

Comment: Do you want users to Restore From Recycle Bin? One would think you're putting files in the Recycle bin in order to delete them, IMHO making this a 2 step process (just cos you want users to see there files in the bin) is un-intuitive. +1 Reed.

Comment: I am simply asking a question, without a context how can you suggest alternatives?